# Android JUnit4 Testing - Where to get Context from?

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, android-context

I have to build an app with sqlite usage. Now I want to write my unit tests. These unit tests should test my class `SQLiteBridge`. `SQLiteBridge` provides DAOs for every child class of Model.

Now I got the problem that I need a context to create my `SQLiteBridge`. `SQLiteBridge` creates and handles a SQLite database on the system..

Where to get the Context-Object from?

My setup is like here (so I'm using Junit4 [thanks god]):
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

EDIT: I hope there is a way like the old `AndroidTestCase` to extend without losing Junit4. :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As described here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide
Use the InstrumentationRegistry to obtain the context.

However if you call `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` directly you may get an exception opening your database. I believe this is because the context returned by getContext() points to the instrumentation's context rather than that of your application / unit test. Instead use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`

For example:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SqliteTest {

    Context mMockContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mMockContext = new RenamingDelegatingContext(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), "test_");
    }
}
```

The RenamingDelegatingContext simply prefixes the file/database names with test_ to prevent you from overwriting data that you may have in the same simulator.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked!
I think I will use Robolectric .. but thanks for this solution! :)

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but the prefix is being ignored and thus the "real" database is being used in the test. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: InstrumentationRegistry cannot be resolved as a symbol

Comment: InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

Answer (score 4):

jUnit 4 (and perhaps other versions of jUnit) and androidx use:

```
ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
```

See: [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#app-context)