# How to get Context for Unit Test

Tags: java, android, android-testing

I'm trying to pass the context into a constructor for a unit test. And I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
```

I've tried the following code.

```
public class Handler {

    @Mock
    MyViewModel viewModel;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
        Handler = new Handler(context, viewModel);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android JUnit4 Testing - Where to get Context from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319838/android-junit4-testing-where-to-get-context-from)

Comment: It doesn't but thanks for the link. I was able to use a @Mock Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add @RunWith annotation with AndroidJUnit runner.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJunit4::class)
public class Handler {

    @Mock
    MyViewModel viewModel;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
        Handler = new Handler(context, viewModel);

    }
}
```

Also add the following dependency if its not addded in the build.gradle(app)

> ```
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
> ```